# Implementing simple Login function in C

Tags: c, authentication

I am trying this login program in C but due to some reasons the program gets stuck in infinity loop the moment user name is entered.I have double checked my code but could not find anything wrong in it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *name="bob";       //test data
char *password="pas";

int user_name()
{
fflush(stdin);
char *c[10],*p[10];
printf("user name enter\n");

if(fgets(c,10,stdin))     //check if any user data entered
{
    if(name==NULL)
  {
    printf("welcome user created\n");
    strcpy(name,c);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("create a password\n");
    fgets(password,10,stdin);
    return 1;
  }
 else
 {
    if(strcmp(name,c)==0)         //if user input matched existing username
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("enter password");
        fgets(p,10,stdin);       //take in password
        if(strcmp(p,password)==0) //compare password
        return 1;


    }

     return 0;
  }

}

int main()
{
 int t=0;
 t=user_name();
 if(t==1)

    printf("welcome");
 else
    printf("sorry");
    return 1;
```

}

Please help me in finding the problem.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` - undefined behavior.

Comment: P.S. The code works fine if user is NULL or not specified,but if a name exists,the infinity loop problem occurs.

Comment: `char *c; scanf("%c",&c);`, `char *password...;scanf("%c",&password);` - undefined behavior. Note that `&c` is `char**`.

Comment: Eugene Sh. why is it undefined behavior?It is the method used to take a non space string in char array

Comment: See updated comment. For the first one - it is explicitly stated in the C standard *If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.* [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2)

Comment: Perhaps reading the manual page for scanf would help you

Comment: also looks like you're going down a road towards some more undefined behavior. Once you get your `scanf` for `password` coded up "correctly", you'll be modifying a string literal, which is also undefined behavior (`password` points to the string literal `"pas"`).

Comment: I've fixed the indentation, but please make sure code is properly indented before posting.

Answer (score 1):

- getting the name should be `scanf("%s",name)`.
- To copy sting in `C` use `strncpy` or similar functions.
- `fflush(stdin)` is UB.
- `c` is a pointer to a `char` - it will just store address of a char variable. But it itself is not a `char`. You need to allocate memory for that. 
  To allocate you can do this:-

> ```
> char *c = malloc(sizeof(*c)*MAXLEN);
> if( c == NULL){
>   // error
> }
> ```

To get the username you should do something like this

```
char name[MAXLEN];

if(fgets(name, MAXLEN, stdin)){
// name read in `name`
}
```

Also you can logically seperate your code like this:-(these are the logical steps)

> - Start the program
> - Get username
> - Validate
> - Password validation

### Necessary hints:

- If  you want to use the username password in different instance of the program then you have to store it somewhere (be it files or database).
- If that's not what you want, then you can simply use a while loop to initiate multiple cases where you take user input. Otherwise how would you verify the password or username set?

---

As per the modified code:-

- You don't need that literal `bob` or `pas` if you are taking input for the first time.
- Use simple input first. `char c[10]` will do. You have declared an array of character pointers.(which can't be used unless you allocate some memory to those pointers).

  Initial solution:-

  ```
  #define MAXLEN 60
  char name[MAXLEN];      //sample data(Just for testing)
  char pas[MAXLEN];  //sample data
  int firstime = 1;
  int user_name()
  {
       char name1[MAXLEN];
       char pas1[MAXLEN];
       if(firstime){    
           printf("user name enter\n");
           scanf("%s",name);
           printf("password enter\n");
           scanf("%s",pas);
           firstime = 0;
           return 1;
       }
       else
       {
           printf("user name enter\n");
           scanf("%s",name1);
           printf("password enter\n");
           scanf("%s",pas1);
           if(strcmp(name,name1) == 0 && strcmp(pas,pas1) == 0)
               return 1;
           else
               return 0;

       }
   }
  ```

Now this is what is the initial code looks like :-

You can replace `scanf` calls with `fgets()`.

```
if(fgets(name,MAXLEN,stdin)==NULL)
{
   //error
}
```

- Also as mentioned before you can try to modify the solution to contain more modular solution but taking the reusable portions and making a function out of it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion.The program is not getting stuck but now there is another problem,even if I type "bob" it say sorry

Comment: @coderredoc That was a bad suggestion. One question per question. Now your answer is invalid.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: But the hints or debugging info provided is sufficient to solve all the problems...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Even after help they don't feel like getting up and working up the solution..even the stupidest or vulnerable solution would be done if someone tries to build up from this answer.

Comment: can anyone tell what went wrong?I know this is a stupid question but I am really wondering how the hell such a simple logic is taking so much time to produce the desired result.

Comment: +coderredoc yes I absolutely understand that I will have to save the previous username and password in a separate file.But right now, I want to make my authentication function working and that is why I have supplied test inputs

Comment: +coderroc nope,I just need to find out what went logically wrong in my implementation.Please point them out to me.No need to send full code.

Comment: @SARTHAKMEHRA.: Post the modified full code...I can give you hint.

Comment: Please look at the code.This time try to reply in a separate answer para

Comment: @SARTHAKMEHRA>: I will get back to you when I get some time( an hour )

Comment: @SARTHAKMEHRA.: Check the naswer